# Why does $\operatorname{Hom}_{RG}(R,M)\simeq\{m\in M:k\cdot m=m\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory

Suppose $R$ is a commutative unital ring, $G$ a finite group, and $M$ a finite dimensional $RG$-module. If $K$ is a subgroup, the invariants of $M$ under $K$ is defined to be
$$
M^K=\operatorname{Hom}_{RK}(R,M).
$$

A more concrete description is given by
$$
M^K\simeq\{m\in M:k\cdot m=m,\ \forall k\in K\}
$$
for all $k\in K$.

Why are these two spaces isomorphic? The only sensible map I could see would be something like sending $(\varphi\colon R\to M)\mapsto\varphi(1)$. Is there perhaps a mistake in the definition of $M^K$, because $R$ doesn't seem like an $RK$-module under the usual multiplication action inherited from the group ring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is right! The map is $(\varphi\colon R\to M)\mapsto\varphi(1)$. The trick here is to see $R$ as a trivial $RK$-module, i.e., $k\cdot r=r$ for all $k\in K$. Then it is easy to see that this map is an isomorphism. For example, to show that is well defined, if $\varphi:R \to M$ is $RK$-linear, $k\cdot \varphi(1)=\varphi(k\cdot 1)=\varphi(1)$. So $\varphi(1)\in M^K$.

Comment: Thanks Nitrogen, I didn't realize we assume $K$ acts trivially on $R$. I thought $k\cdot\varphi(1)=\varphi(k\cdot 1)=\varphi(k)$...